# Разделение значения в текстбоксе

Tags: html

Есть текстбокс или input, в котором введено, что-то вроде:

```
оывар длоыфвр алоыфв  $ дыловар лыовар лыво  $ лдывоапрвлыаопрывап
```

Условно можно разделить это на 3 части: 1 - от начала и до первого $ (не включая $); 2 - от начала первого $ (не включая $) и до второго $ (не включая $); 3 - от начала второго $ (не включая $) и до конца.

Под этим текстбоксом еще 3 текстбокса. Как сделать, чтобы значения трех нижних текстбоксов автоматически равнялись одной "условной" части от первого текстбокса?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Используя jQuery:

```
$('#input1').val($('#input').val().split(' $ ')[0]);
$('#input2').val($('#input').val().split(' $ ')[1]);
$('#input3').val($('#input').val().split(' $ ')[2]);
```

Comment: а можно как то через функцию в input в onKeyUp ?

Comment: Ну можно обернуть то, что я написал в функцию, и вызывать её по событию onKeyUp инпута. Можно написать универсальную функцию (например вычислять номер инпута, в который пишется очередная "условная часть"). Можно навесить событие на инпут, например, вот так:

    $('#input').keyUp(function () {
        pices = $(this).val().split(' $ ');
        //пробегаемся по массиву pices и присваеваем значения куда надо
    });